# How To Debug Node_Modules Library? Floating Label not working

Tags: node.js, angular, intellij-idea, webpack, angular-material

I have a Angular App, and I have the problem when I use

```
<mat-form-field><textarea name="" matInput id="" placeholder="Test"></textarea></mat-form-field>
```

the label `Test` will not float to the top, it stays where it is.

Now I want to **debug** *Angular Material*, which is a *NPM Dependency* stored inside `node_modules`. I tried with *IntelliJ*, set a `breakpoint`, but it won't step into it.

I don't know if it's possible, maybe *Webpack* is not allowing this.

Comment: Can you you show us a working example? The float should work by default. `<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="never">` will cancel float.

Comment: Instead of `placeholder="Test"`, try adding `<mat-placeholder>Test</mat-placeholder>` to the `<mat-form-field>`. If that doesn't work, my guess is that you have not imported MatInput into your module.

Comment: where did you set a breakpoint - in material module code? What does your run configuration look like?